# I want to trim a string in a way that a character will repeat only once

Tags: java, json, bukkit

I am making a program in java, which gets `title` and `current_version` from this JSON API `https://api.spigotmc.org/simple/0.1/index.php?action=getResource&id=<RESOURCE ID TO BE INPUT`

It returns the name and the version, then I use it to make a link, and the format of link is pretty simple
`https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/<TITLE>.<ID>/`

A lot of times it works, but in some cases like the title is returned as `ChristmasPresents | [1.7-1.16]`, the the link to their page is `https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/christmaspresents-1-7-1-16.39859/`, So what I want to do is, trim it in a way that, all the special characters will be trimmed, but the result is like this `https://spigotmc.org/resources/christmaspresents----1-7-1-16-.39859`.

How can i cut those extra `-` I only want one, (It can repeat after a number or alphabet

Thanks

Comment: Something is not clear here. If you are getting ChristmasPresents | [1.7-1.16], where are those extra - characters coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to replace all special characters with `-` but want no consecutive `-` in the output. For this, you could just use a regular expression to `replaceAll` `\W+` with `-`:

```
var title = "ChristmasPresents | [1.7-1.16]";
title = title.replaceAll("\\W+","-");
// "ChristmasPresents-1-7-1-16-"
```

Note that this adds a `-` at the end, which you probably do not want. Unless I'm missing something `String.strip` will only strip whitespace, so the easiest way might be to replace the special chars with single spaces first, then `strip`, then replace the spaces with `-`:

```
title = title.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\W+"," ").strip().replace(" ", "-");
// "christmaspresents-1-7-1-16"
```